# AcharEngine making Date related graph

Tags: java, android, eclipse, achartengine

I am trying to make a plot of weight of an animal stored with soem specific date. I have Weight Class with two vars , Date and Weight.

Here is the code I am using.

```
else if (str.equals("Weight"))
    {
        mDbHelper.open();
        wtArray = mDbHelper.getWeight();
        mDbHelper.close();

       TimeSeries diaSeries = new TimeSeries("Weight");

        for ( int i =0; i <wtArray.size(); i++)
        {
           Weight wt = wtArray.get(i);
           diaSeries.add(wt.date, wt.weight);
        }


        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(diaSeries);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        graphLayout.addView(ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
```

The problem with this code is, it never shows anything on x Axis and no graph line is also displayed.

Secondly, What If I want to show data from specific date to another date? Like from Feb to March etc.?

Comment: Are you sure the TimeSeries contains anything?

Comment: ofc it does, i have checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code to build an example to compile and run for me. Please see the code below that displays a chart correctly. The code builds an `Intent`, so you will have to change the last line to build a `View`.

So, if you are really sure that you really put data into the model than you should check the layout. You are probably not adding the chart view to your layout correctly.

```
List<Date> wtArray = new ArrayList<Date>();
double[] weight = new double[] { 70, 71, 74, 73, 70, 71, 75, 76, 75, 73, 75, 73 };
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  wtArray.add(new Date(108, i, 1));
}
TimeSeries diaSeries = new TimeSeries("Weight");

for (int i = 0; i < wtArray.size(); i++) {
  diaSeries.add(wtArray.get(i), weight[i]);
}

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
dataset.addSeries(diaSeries);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
renderer.setFillPoints(true);
mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

return ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```